# Undefined mapStateToProps React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, undefined, redux-thunk, reducers

Hey I have badgeNumber constantly returned as undefined and I really don't understand why. I will appreciate any help thanks.

My Reducer:

```js
import {OPEN_DROPDOWN, ADD_TASK, REMOVE_TASK, CLOSE_DROPDOWN} from '../types/MenuTypes';

const initialState = {
  badgeNumber: 6,
  drop: false,
  tasks: [] 
};

export function reducerMenuEntry(startMenuState = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_DROPDOWN:
      return Object.assign({}, startMenuState, {
        ...startMenuState,
        drop: true
      });

    case CLOSE_DROPDOWN:
      return Object.assign({}, startMenuState, {
        ...startMenuState,
        drop: false
      });

    case REMOVE_TASK:
    case ADD_TASK:
      return Object.assign({}, startMenuState, {
        ...startMenuState,
        badgeNumber: action.badgeNumber,
        tasks: action.tasks
      });

    default:
      return initialState;
  }
}
```

And the component where I try to display data:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ToolsBar extends Component {
  render() {
    const {badgeNumber} = this.props;
    alert(badgeNumber);
    return (
      <Toolbar {...this.props.getActionsProps({})}>
        <ToolbarButton>
          <Badge badgeContent={badgeNumber} />
        </ToolbarButton>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    drop: state.drop,
    badgeNumber: state.badgeNumber
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ToolsBar);
```

Store:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import RootReducer from './reducers/RootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default () => {
  return createStore(RootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
};
```

Actions but currently they are not completely implemented. I want to display the static value before modify them via actions:

```js
import { OPEN_DROPDOWN, ADD_TASK, REMOVE_TASK, CLOSE_DROPDOWN} from "../types/MenuTypes";

export const open = () => {
  return { type: OPEN_DROPDOWN }
};

export const close = () => {
  return { type: CLOSE_DROPDOWN }
};

export function addTask(tasks, badgeNum){
  badgeNum++;
  return { type:ADD_TASK, tasks, badgeNum}
};

export function removeTask (tasks, badgeNum){
  badgeNum--;
  return { type: REMOVE_TASK, tasks, badgeNum}
};
```

Combined Reducer:

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {reducerUpdatePageEntry} from './UpdatePageReducer';
import {reducerSearchPageEntry} from './SearchPageReducer';
import {reducerSharedEntry} from './SharedReducer';
import {reducerUploadPageEntry} from './UploadPageReducer';
import {reducerMenuEntry} from './MenuReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  updateStates: reducerUpdatePageEntry,
  displaySearchStates: reducerSearchPageEntry,
  sharedStates: reducerSharedEntry,
  uploadStates: reducerUploadPageEntry,
  menuStates: reducerMenuEntry
});
```

Comment: Is that prop coming from somewhere via an asynchronous operation?

Comment: I'm sorry I am not good with Redux I thought that they are passed via the store

Comment: Ok, but where is this `badgeNumber` value coming from? Is it static in your code or is it coming from from an API? It is better to add your action creator codes. You have thunk middleware, so probably there is an async job.

Comment: Currently is static I will update the comment so I can show the actions too.

Comment: Also, your reducers please. Since we can't see what does your `state` look like right now.

Comment: About this line: `import RootReducer from './reducers/RootReducer';` Is the reducer file with the `reducerMenuEntry ` function called RootReducer?

Comment: Ok, question's been updated. Do you have one top level state (I suspect that) or do you open this reducer's state something like `menuEntry`?

Comment: If I understand you're question properly I have a combined reducer I post it too

Comment: yes, please post your combined reducer

Comment: That's because your store name is whatever you called it in combineReducers for example `state.reducerMenuEntry.badgeNumber`

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a wrong path specified in mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    drop: state.menuStates.drop,
    badgeNumber: state.menuStates.badgeNumber
  };
};
```

---

Additionally be careful about

```
default:
  return initialState;
```

I guess it should be

```
default:
  return startMenuState;
```

because if you return `initialState` the state will be reset with each unhandled action.

Answer (score 0):

When you combine reducers, you kind of create multiple states on your application.

Your mapStateToProps function should look like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    drop: state.menuStates.drop,
    badgeNumber: state.menuStates.badgeNumber
  };
};
```

---

One more thing: If you are already using object spread, you dont need Object.assign

Just use it like this:

```
return {
    ...startMenuState,
    drop: false
  });
```